# How to check if column titles are valid in Python from a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, validation

I have a CSV file containing data has the following column titles: `first_name`, `last_name` and `email`. I would like to validate that the CSV file in that it must have the columns ordered in the order shown above. I have implemented the code but the problem is getting the column titles. The reason I'm insisting to verify this order is that I am creating patient objects that have `firstname` ,`lastname` and `email` as fields and if the CSV file is re-ordered then wrong data will end up being added to the fields.

```
if file_serializer.is_valid():
    data = self.request.data.get('file')
    data_set = data.read().decode('UTF-8')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)

    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
        # Add validation here
        print(column)
        obj, created = Patient.objects.get_or_create(
                firstname=column[0],
                lastname=column[1],
                email=column[2]
            )
```

**CSV screenshot**

[image]

**Sample Text**

```
first_name,last_name,email
Shaylynn,Klimentyev,sklimentyev0@cisco.com
Thaddeus,Grushin,tgrushin1@umn.edu
Hayden,Cranmer,hcranmer2@nationalgeographic.com
Colet,Ferfulle,cferfulle3@unesco.org
Ernestine,Hardi,ehardi4@virginia.edu
Freddi,Knagges,fknagges5@ifeng.com
```

Comment: Please add the text of csv file instead of an image

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh the record contains 1000 items.

Comment: Then you can added maybe first 5-10 rows, but not an image

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh before I do some task I would like to validate that the file has the columns arranged in the order shown else an exception will be raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't really matter whether the columns are in the correct order, as long as they have the correct column titles. You can use [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to process those titles:

```
for row in csv.DictReader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'):
    print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'], row['email'])
```

If you really insist on verifying the order, you can do that too:

```
list(row.keys()) == ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

Comment: The reason I am insisting is that I'm creating patient objects if someone uploads a CSV file in a different order then there will be a problem. I will be having data going to the wrong fields in the patient object as shown in the update above.

Comment: Again, if you process the fields **by their name** and not by their order, it doesn't matter what order they're in…!

Comment: @pmutua: The data would _not_ go into the wrong fields if you call `Patient.objects.get_or_create(firstname=row['first_name'], lastname=row['last_name'], email=row['email'])` and it wouldn't matter what order they were in the csv file.

Comment: @martineau If OP was a little more consistent with the naming, they could even do `Patient.objects.get_or_create(**row)`…

Comment: I agree if that is the case, I am trying to `print(row['first_name'])` but I'm getting a `key error`. When I print `row` I get Items in this format: `OrderedDict([('Shaylynn', 'Christina'), ('Klimentyev', 'Choak'), ('sklimentyev0@cisco.com', 'cchoak6@gizmodo.com')])`

Comment: @pmutua Probably because you're advancing `next(io_string)`, which skips the *actual* header line. Remove that so `DictReader` is able to read the actual first line.

Comment: @deceze You are actually right the `key error` is resolved and it does not matter the order they are in. This is actually a better approach to resolve this.

Comment: @pmutua: Also note that if you instead created a named reader via `csvreader = csv.DictReader(...)` before the `for` loop reading the rows, you could then see what fields it automatically found in the file by printing the value of `csvreader.fieldnames` as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.fieldnames).

Answer (score 0):

```
myiter = csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|")
header = next(myiter)
print("HEADER:", header)
for column in myiter:
    # Add validation here
    print(column)
```